# Associations Ruby on Rails to make joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new on ruby and I'm  trying to do  a good association :), but I have some problems to write them into the ruby models have the following:

Games (id <-> game_id)  Players (user_id <-> id) Users

I think it should be more or less as:
A player has many games but belongs to a one user and a user has many players

I want to be able to do a join between 3 classes i.e. Game and  Player to get users

Am I in the correct way?

Comment: I would recommend that you review this first: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your models set up with the has_many and belongs_to methods correctly the way to do the join in very simple

```
User.joins(:games, :players)
```

Hope this helps

There is a really good guide to the whole query interface here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thank you! that was so helpful :)